# Calculated column to calculate approved status workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

How to use calculated column to calculate approved status workflow?

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
IF([Approve status]="Pendding", 1, 0)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here exactly using calculated column?

Comment: You cannot count multiple items based on status using calculated column. calculated column can only reference the column values from single item/row. easiest way is to use grouping, check my updated answer below for more information.

Comment: Ik I want to create 3 columns, each column will count a status  , then will sum all the 1s

Comment: In that case, you can create 3 columns for 3 different status values & use formulas like: `=IF([Approval Status]="Pending",1,0)` for Pending calculated column and `=IF([Approval Status]="Approved",1,0)` for Approved calculated column. Refer to the formula & column settings given in my answer.

Comment: =IF([Approval Status]="Pending",1,0) doesn't work

Comment: Are you getting any error while saving formula or value is not updated correctly in calculated column? Make sure you are using correct display name of column and choice option (Pending: case-sensitive). Also, try using `=IF([Approval Status]="Pending";1;0)`.

Comment: It says "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported"

Comment: Are you trying to create a new calculated column or using "calculated value" (default value) option of columns? Did you try the formula using semicolons as mentioned in my answer and above comments?

Comment: @GaneshSanap Yes I'm trying to create a new calculated column or using "calculated value" , yes tried the formula using semicolons

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of where are you adding the formula? What is the data type of Approval status column, choice?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a calculated column based on approval status column, use formula like:

```
=IF([Approval Status]="Pending",1,0)
```

This will return `1` value in calculated column when Approval Status is equal to "Pending" else it will return `0` as value of calculated column.

**Calculated column settings**:

[image]

---

Follow steps given in my answer to create a calculated column in a list at: [Formula does not work for SharePoint/Lists](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/formula-does-not-work-for-sharepoint-lists/m-p/3598229/highlight/true#M62834)

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on language or regional settings on your site). In that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`) at all places in above formula.
2. You cannot use "calculated value" option of existing columns as this option cannot reference other columns in list in formula. So, you have to create a column with "calculated" data type for referencing other columns in list in calculated formula.
3. You have to use the correct "display" name of Approval Status column in your formula.

---

**Update from comments**:

If you want to get the count of number of approved, rejected and pending items, easiest way is to use the **Grouping** in list view on Approval Status column.

Follow Microsoft documentation for more information: [Use grouping to modify a list or library view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-grouping-to-modify-a-list-or-library-view-18548b63-a869-4fcf-89b1-ba3d04784df7)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the calculated column to return a Yes/No value; try this:

```
IF([Approve status]="Pendding", true, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this, the Approval Status field is a lookup field and not applicable for calculated fields. My approach to the issue would be to create a separate calendar view of items with a filter of Approval Status = Pending. This way, approvers can toggle between the approved and pending data and easily distinguish what needs to be approved.

---

**If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.**